# Setting up SharePoint 2010 Excel Services

Tags: excel-services, office-web-apps, deployment

How do you set up Excel Services for SharePoint 2010?

I’ve installed the Office Web Apps (wcsetup.exe) and created a new Excel service in central administration.

But I’m now stuck on what to do next - do I need to turn it on in a document library?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" Site Collection feature.

And Office Web Apps is not Excel Services. In Office Web Apps (is OWA the correct acroynom?) you have the Excel editor/browser which is not the same as Excel Services.

Answer (score 2):

You first have to add your site collection url to the list of trusted excel services locations.  After that you should have the option to open in web in any document libraries in that site collection.

Comment: Is that necessary in SP2010, isnt all of SP trusted now?

Comment: Well, you still have trusted locations but it does seem that by default if the url starts with http:// or your webapplication url then they are trusted.

Comment: Yeah, that what was I thought (and verified now). Ie the difference between 2007 and 2010 is that 2007 has no default trusted locations and 2010 by default trusts all SharePoint sites hooked to the service app.

Comment: so I should be able to select the excel document in the library and have an option in the ribbon to view in the browser?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve; view it using the Office Web Apps or using the Excel Svcs?

Comment: good point, i'm getting confused; i'd like to view the excel work book int he browser.